# Formatting Value Decimal Microsoft Report C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report

Hello I have a problem with C # software that uses Microsoft's report, I should print a decimal value n2 in the format, but when I print the report inverts inverts the point with the point, how do I fix? I put below the setting of the image size and n2 of the printed report

**Setting Report:**

[image]

**Printed Report**

[image]

**Currency Windows Settings**

[image]

**Visual Studio Setting and Report**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things you have to check for solving this problem.

#### 1. Disable `Use regional Settings`

[image: The setting]

This will ensure the `.` and the `,` will be used suitable as currency to the client which prints the report.

#### 2. Check Server's / Clienst's `Regional and Language Options`

Open "New Task" with **Windows Key + R** and type in `intl.cpl` for getting them. Then click on `Additional Settings` and check the tab with `Currency`.

After changing this you have to log off your windows account and login again for applying this settings.

#### 3. Set Format directly to `#.#,00`

Also make sure this field is empty if you are using solutions from above.

[image: Properties window]

---

### Update

There is your bad boy:

[image: Prop Windows]

It should be `#.#,00` but the current set format value equals to your wrong output. This field is overriding your settings.

Comment: I have disable regional setting, top I loaded my currency operating system settings. I tried to print the report after disabling the regional settings, but does not change anything

Comment: @RiccardoPirani Are you printing the report on the same machine as where you design it?

Comment: is the printing on the same machine where I'm planning, although from where I fetch the data sql server database to print the report is on a windows server 2012

Comment: No, check the currency settings on the machine of the `SQL Server`.

Comment: I checked, the currency settings are the same as on the machine where I'm planning

Comment: @RiccardoPirani **facepalm me** - simply switch your Property from above from `Number` to `Currency`.

Comment: Use the rdlc report, I tried to set currency instead of number in the report settings, but does not change anything, I had a doubt, the windows 10 on the machine language where I'm planning is in English, but the currency is set in Italian . It could be that I have to put the operating system language in Italian?

Comment: @RiccardoPirani No, it shouldn't. Have you tried restarting the system after making changes on the clients settings? Or are you using `Dynamics NAV` ? Another thing you can check is the the `Format` Property of your field in the designer and set it to `#.#,00`.

Comment: I tried to restart after changing the settings does not change anything, I also tried to set #. #, 00 and the result does not change, using microsoft report viewer

Comment: @RiccardoPirani Can you add the Properties Windows from the Textbox with the number to your question? This is really wired.

Comment: I added the image above with the settings of the textbox and visual studio report!

Comment: I had already tried changing the format to #. #, 00 the problem is that the value that comes out of me is: 1234.00,

should print me 1.234,00

Comment: @RiccardoPirani this is definitely the problem. Change the format to `C2`.

Comment: I had already tried with C2, if I put it 1,234.000 press at me, so I should print it: 1234.000

Comment: i have solve  with Set Format directly to #.#,00 thank you